Git - How to merge main branch to child branch if all files directories have been totally changed (wrapped in SPM)
I have a situation in my Swift iOS development project.
20 days ago, I created a branch named Modular_Approach from the Main-Branch. It's an enterprise application, so it took quite a while to convert the entire codebase into modules. Now, with Swift Package Managers (SPMs) created, 80% of the files have been moved to different SPMs instead of being in one project.
During these 20 days, my team of 10 people made significant changes to the files that are now in the SPMs. I'm unsure how to proceed with merging the main branch into my Modular_Approach branch because 80% of the files have been relocated.
Can anyone suggest a smart solution for this situation?

you will have to take a pull and merge all files manually

Did you actually try to do the merge? I think there is a good chance git will do the appropriate thing and recognize the files being moved and propagate the changes there automatically.

@KrzysiekKarbowiak I tried it now, but git dropped a lot of code.

Some files are collapsed, like showing some other file content.

When you do a git merge there will (likely be) conflicts to resolve when you type git status.  Here's how to resolve those on the command line.
